# How to prevent my custom UIControl to pass touch event through underlying view

Tags: ios, uibutton, uicontrol, uiresponder, uievent

I create a custom `UIControl`, but when I tap on my control, touch event always passing through to `superview`.

Here is my set up and sample project for this https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2271974/FunWithUIControl.zip

View with tap gesture
- UIButton
- MyCustomControl

When I tap on UIButton, tap gesture didn't receive any touch event.
When I tap on my custom control, tap gesture get touch event.

What is the proper way to replicate `UIButton` behavior?